# Python Selenium - Individual table items into dataframe etc

Tags: python, selenium, dataframe, web-scraping

I am new to Python and selenium, so can't come up with a solution here:

I try to receive information from the following website: "http://avi2.osamsterdam.nl/index.mpl"

This table should be brought into a dataframe (etc.): [table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skcBG.png)
So far, my code is able to select the respective neighbourhood (buurt) and open the data table of it. The goal is to later loop over this process, but that I can do myself.

The problem is, that the table is in a strange format, which makes it hard to "grab" the variables. Furthermore, I am still puzzling how to put the data together, without messing up information.

Any ideas how I can grab the items (maybe one example)? 
What would you recommend me to do, to bring it into a similar format (date column headers, indices as row names)?

Here is my code:

```
website = "http://avi2.osamsterdam.nl/index.mpl"
driver.get(website) # runs webdriver 
buurt='//a[@class="expandable" and contains(text(),"Buurt")]'

area = driver.find_element_by_id("geo")
area.click()

#select buurt
option=men_menu = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, buurt)))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(option).perform()

buurten = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="geo"]/li/ul/li[3]')
x = buurten.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
opt_l = []  
for e in x:
    print (e.text)
    #opt_l.append(e.text)

x[1].click() # later repeat for all! 

# How to select indiviudal items and make sure it goes into dataframe?
# does not work as of here: 
table = driver.find_element_by_id("kenmerkoverzicht")
dates = table.find_elements_by_css_selector('/th')
for e in dates:
    print (e.text)
```

Comment: '/th' is not a css selector, try using 'th'

Comment: Pass the whole table to pandas `read_html` method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html you dont need to parse it yourself

Comment: @BreaksSoftware: it still does not print anything in the last line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your existing code, You'll need to wait for that table, and it's contents to become visible before you can do much with them (also note the proper CSS_SELECTOR for the th element).

```
    table = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'kenmerkoverzicht')))
    dates = WebDriverWait(table, 5).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'th')))
```

You can then proceed to pull the row and cell data into your own dataframe.  I like the idea from @Dalvenjia to use pandas to pull the data in directly.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the panda idea,  `pandaframe = pd.read_html(table,thousands=' ', header=0, index_col=0)[0]`  but get the following error message: TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'WebElement'  Do I need to convert the table somehow? The website url also does not work (results in an empty frame)

Comment: solved it! if anyone needs the answer, please comment

Comment: My guess is that you used .innerHTML() or .outerHTML() on the table webElement to pass the html to pandas?